# How to release std string from memory management duties?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, memory

I have a string by value and a function that takes in a char pointer and length and when finished calls a callback which is a lambda expression provided on that function call. I want my string data to be deallocated on that callback -not when scope exits. There is no move into lambda in c++11 and current wrapper implementations I found can not be passed as void(*fun)() function arguments. Are there ways to move string or release it from its memory duties in c++11?

So original API was in C

```
void Send(const void * _topic, int length, void (*OnSend)());
```

That activated other sender thread and called OnSend after sending data. Zero-Copy was main point of all this.

And I wanted to call it from C++ and move into this a real string, keeping zero-copy.

Ended up with rewriting core API in C++ - doing such thing from C without Pools/const size Ring buffers is really hard! So having a `std::function` and `std::bind` it all gets much simpler. Yet now C API wraps C++ one...

While C++ part looks like this:

```
void Send(std::string && _data) {
    const auto data_ptr = &_data;

    std::function<void()> OnDataRemoval = std::bind(
        [](std::string && d){},
            std::move(_data)
    );

     Send(data_ptr, OnDataRemoval);
}
```

Comment: Callback is called from another thread

Comment: can you post sample code?

Comment: Your design sounds broken. If you want something to be deallocable at any time, use a dynamically allocated object with a pointer to it. (*Without* changing this objects internals)

Comment: There's no guaranteed way to make a std::string release its memory before its lifetime ends, if that's what you're asking. However this might work: `s.swap( std::string{} );` . BTW "callback is called from another thread" is very suspicious, is that really your design? What happens if the function exits before the callback happens?

Comment: "What happens if the function exits before the callback happens" that is what I am trying to getaround - a function exits long before the callback thus string shall be freed from its memory obligations or I'llget corrupted memory(

Comment: @DuckQueen So you mean you want to take over management of the memory currently in the string? Update the post to say that. It's impossible, all you can do is take a copy of the string contents and manually manage that. Suggest changing the function's interface if that is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your string has to outlive the scope of the calling function, it doesn't make sense to tie its lifetime to that specific scope.

Which means you should allocate your string dynamically:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <future>

void    func(const char *str, int length, std::function<void()> callback)
{
  std::async
    (std::launch::async,
     [str, length, callback]
     {
       for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
         std::cout << str[i];
       std::cout << std::endl;

       callback();
     });
}

int     main(void)
{
  std::shared_ptr<std::string>   str = std::make_shared<std::string>("test");

  func(str->c_str(), str->length(),
       [str]
       {
         std::cout << "callback" << std::endl;
       });
}
```

You could imagine better solutions with generalised lambda capture but since you are limited to `c++11`, you can't use that

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mistaken. It's unlikely that the callback must be a *lambda*. That's an unnamed type with `operator()`. The callback cannot detect the name, so a *named* functor will also work:

```
void foo(std::string s)
{
   struct functor { std::shared_ptr<std::string> data; operator()() const {/*NOP*/} };
   functor F { std::make_shared<std::string>(std::move(s)) };
   callback(F.data->c_str(), F.data->size(), std::move(F));
}
```

Note that the `std::move(F)` is just needed because we named `functor F` for clarity.